# Java DOM: Get all parents list

Tags: java, xml, dom

I Need to list all the Elements which contain at least one child. For example, in the below XML, H,I,T have at least one child field each. I Need to list out H,I,T only & ignore other parents such as G_GT, Rec etc.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Doc>
  <Rec>
    <H>
      <Key>H</Key>
      <F1>1</F1>
      <I>
        <Key>I</Key>
        <F2>08</F2>
        <G_GT>
          <T>
            <Key>T</Key>
            <F3>1</F3>
          </T>
          <T>
            <Key>T</Key>
            <F3>2</F3>
          </T>
        </G_GT>
      </I>
    </H>
  </Rec>
</Doc>
```

The Code should give Output as **H,I,T**.
I am working on Java with DOM parser. Could anyone suggest how to do this in Java using DOM? I cannot use functions as getElementByTagName etc as I can get XML with different parent & child names. Thus, I have to avoid any hardcoding of child or parent Name.

Regards,
Phil

Comment: `</Doc>` missing at the bottom of xml?

Comment: Your rule seems to be wrong or incomplete. When your condition is `at least one child`. Why not `<G_GT>`?

Comment: G_GT has no fields. It only contains T which has further fields. I Need T but not G_GT

Comment: T has fields Key & F3 which do not have any child, thus I Need their Parent which is T. As G_GT does not have any childless field i.e a field which contains a value such as <F3>2</F3>, I do not Need G_GT

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Does it work for you? If not, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the parent ELEMENT_NODE of an ELEMENT_NODE without a child ELEMENT_NODE you might start with following snippet

```
NodeList elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
Set<String> nodesNames = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++) {
      Node node = elements.item(i);
      NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
      for (int j = 0; j < nodeList.getLength(); j++) {
            Node currentNode = nodeList.item(j);
            if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                 nodesNames.add(node.getParentNode().getNodeName());
                 break;
            }
      }
}
System.out.println("nodesNames = " + nodesNames);
```

would produce the output

```
[H, I, T]
```